# How to send authorization, cookie headers with javascript fetch API

Tags: reactjs, apache, localhost

I'm trying to send authorization headers to a API endpoint that is running on 127.0.0.1:8888 from a react app running on 127.0.0.1:3000.

```
var data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append('code', code);
fetch('http://localhost:8888/users/verifyEmail', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'authorization': 'Bearer '+ bearer,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'
    },
    body: data
})
```

The requests gets set to an `OPTIONS` instead of a `POST`.

[image]

In my endpoint that accepts the request I have the headers set

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8888/');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, bearer, content-type, accept');
```

Comment: Try this: Remove `authorization` from headers and pass it as object to separate prop `auth` like `headers`.

Comment: What is your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) module and set up the `ProxyPass` directives:

```
ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8888 
ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:8888
```

Then in your React app, all http requests to https://example.com/api (you can use `` `${window.location.origin}/api` `` to avoid hardcoding your website url) will be proxied to your server instead, with cookies preserved.

Comment: This is added in the apache2/httpd.conf` file or the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: It should be in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I added `<IfModule proxy_module>
    ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8888
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8888
</IfModule>` and it worked after starting apache.

Answer (score 0):

The port at `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be **3000**